# Extract CAPTCHA images

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml, captcha

I'm building training set for Neuron Network from various digits extracted from *CAPTCHA* images.
I'm using **Python 2.7.3**, **lxml** library and **XPath** selector.

To get right images from captcha I need to extract `img src` which is loaded dynamic into www and every time is different, So my Python code is:

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree, html

adres_prefix = "https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/"
adres_sufix = etree.XPath('string(//img[@class="captcha"]/@src)')
sock = urllib.urlopen("https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx")
htmlSource = sock.read()                             
sock.close()
root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
result2 = adres_sufix(root)
www = adres_prefix + result2
print www
```

So every time I'm getting www:

```
https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/captcha.ashx?id=1b7d2b6d-70a6-4ce3-bedd-fe89038fb7f3&empty=1
```

what is wrong because when copy this link into my browser I'm getting nothing.

The source page with [CAPTCHA](https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx)

I have no idea what's wrong. Why XPath selector getting ***'&empty=1'*** ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original HTML source DOES have "empty=1", so your code is correct. To get the image, just trim off the "&empty=1" part.

https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/captcha.ashx?id=1b7d2b6d-70a6-4ce3-bedd-fe89038fb7f3